# hasError is not working; Spring 3 MVC Validation with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

hasError is not working; Spring 3 MVC Validation with Hibernate!

Maybe I am not doing this right but can someone tell me what my hasErrors() is false.  I am puttting errors is my form but the hasErrors is never try?

Controaller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processValidatinForm(@ModelAttribute(" article") Article  article,
                BindingResult result) {

                System.out.println("In");

 if (result.hasErrors()) {
                    System.out.println("I found errors");
                       return "addArticle";
                }
                // Add the saved validationForm to the model

                articleService.addArticle( article);
                return "redirect:/articles.html";
            }
```

Form:
@Entity
@Table(name = "article")
public class Article {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "article_id")
private Long articleId;

@NotEmpty
@Size(max = 20)
@Column(name = "article_name", nullable = false, length=20)
private String articleName;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "article_desc", nullable = false)
private String articleDesc;

@Column(name = "date_added")
private Date addedDate;

public Article() {      
}

public Long getArticleId() {
    return articleId;
}

public void setArticleId(Long articleId) {
    this.articleId = articleId;
}

public String getArticleName() {
    return articleName;
}

public void setArticleName(String articleName) {
    this.articleName = articleName;
}

public String getArticleDesc() {
    return articleDesc;
}

public void setArticleDesc(String articleDesc) {
    this.articleDesc = articleDesc;
}

public Date getAddedDate() {
    return addedDate;
}

public void setAddedDate(Date addedDate) {
    this.addedDate = addedDate;
}
```

}

Comment: It could be a problem with your Spring XML configuration, for example if the annotation support isn't configured correctly. Can you post your Spring XML configuration files?

Comment: it will not let me post it, please email me stutteringjohnsmith@gmail.com and I will email it to you

Comment: of course it lets you post it. Just indent it with 4 spaces.

Comment: thanks @gutch it was the Spring XML coniguratio @Bozho how do  accept the answers

Comment: @Stuttering John there is a tick right below the vote counter of the answer. tick it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If JSR-303 validation is setup properly (you have hibernate-validator jar, and `<mvc:annoatation-driven />`) then you should just use `@Valid @ModelAttribute(..) ..`

Comment: @Hey Bozho I got it working with this code @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String processValidatinForm(@Valid Article article,
    BindingResult result, Map model) {
    System.out.println("In");
                if (result.hasErrors()) {
                 System.out.println("I found errors");
                        return "addArticle";
                }
                // Add the saved validationForm to the model
          
                articleService.addArticle( article);
          return "redirect:/articles.html";
            }

Comment: @Bozho Could you take a look at my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886038/how-to-turn-on-annotation-driven-validation-in-spring-4  I always get the `errors.hasErrors()` return false.