# Why the errors.hasErrors() always return false in Spring 4 annotated form validation?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I tried to implement the `annotated form input validation` in Spring 4.

The following tutorials just don't work.

1. http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/spring-mvc-form-validation-with-annotations-2.html
2. http://codetutr.com/2013/05/28/spring-mvc-form-validation/

The symptoms are the same: the `errors.hasErrors()` always return `false`.

And some reader of the above tutorial 2 reported the identical issue, too.

[image]

This is the model object `Spitter` :

```
public class Spitter {

    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 16)
    private String username="default name";

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 25)
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 30)
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 30)
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @Email
    private String email;

    public Spitter() {
    }

    public Spitter(String username, String password, String firstName,
            String lastName, String email) {
        this(null, username, password, firstName, lastName, email);
    }

    public Spitter(Long id, String username, String password, String firstName,
            String lastName, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(@Size(min = 5, max = 16) String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object that) {
        return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, that, "firstName",
                "lastName", "username", "password", "email");
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this, "firstName",
                "lastName", "username", "password", "email");
    }

}
```

This the form JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="f" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Spitter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
          href="<c:url value="/resources/style.css" />" >
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Register</h1>

    <f:form method="POST" commandName="spitter" modelattribute="spitter">
      f-First Name: <f:input path="firstName" /><br/>
      f-Last Name: <f:input path="lastName" /><br/>
      f-Email: <f:input path="email" /><br/>
      f-User Name: <f:input path="username" /><br/>
      f-Password: <f:input path="password" /><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </f:form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am using:

- [validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final)
- [hibernate-validator-5.0.1.Final.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.0.1.Final)

**This question is solved at here!**
[How to turn on annotation driven validation in Spring 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886038/how-to-turn-on-annotation-driven-validation-in-spring-4/27903277#27903277)

Comment: You must not have any errors.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I intentionally input some incorrect input. It stills report no error. I will post some code snippet.

Comment: Could you post your form and Spitter class? It's possible that the form has different name (not "spitter" as expected) so the Spitter is empty. Check what exctly you send from browser and compare with values in the **spitter**

Comment: @StanislavL I can see the posted values populated into the model object in the Controller's handler method. The value is what I input. It should fail the validation but actually not.

Comment: I am wondering if the validation logic is ever invoked at all. But I don't know how to check that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn on annotation driven validation in Spring 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886038/how-to-turn-on-annotation-driven-validation-in-spring-4)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to tell Spring to enable JSR-303 validation. If you are using an xml way, try registering

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>  in your context xml
```

or if you are using java style:

```
@EnableWebMvc atop your context loading class
```

Hope this solves

Comment: I guess I already did that. I had 2 java style config class. Both of them have been annotated with `@EnableWebMvc`. And I have deleted all the xml config files.